# Do I need ts-morph or tailwindcss for an Electron production build?

Tags: node.js, electron, ts-morph

I am packaging my first Electron app. I noticed a lot of modules inside the `app.asar` of my Electron app and I don't think they should be in there.

AFAIK it's a dev dependency but ends up in the Electron app. It's fairly **big** in size, but I am not sure where it comes from and how to exclude it. What is a good way to determine if I need a specific module for a production build? Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Which is your packager?

Comment: I use `webpack`, but I found which module adds these files and filed an issue